# Reshaping the data for a multinomial regression

Tags: r, categorical-data, multinomial

I am currently learning about the multinomial logit estimator and I want to use it to estimate a model in `R` with the `mlogit` package. After reading extensively on the subject, it was clear that an important step in the process is the reshaping of the data using the `mlogit.data()` function. My data frame contains the following information:

1. `satisfaction`: which is a categorical variable from 1 (very dissatisfied) to 5 (very satisfied.
2. `education`: which is the number of years of education of the individual
3. `country`: which is the country of origin of the individual
4. `average_income`: which is the average income in the country

Here is a visual represention of the data frame:

```
> dat
   country satisfaction education income
1        1            3        12    750
2        1            5        13    750
3        1            2        10    750
4        3            4        13    675
5        3            5        14    675
6        3            4        11    675
7        3            1        14    675
8        2            1        11    820
9        2            5        14    820
10       2            3        12    820
```

The `mlogit()` function does not seem to like it in this form. I am trying to estimate the model with `satisfaction` as the dependent variable and `education` as the independent variable.

How can I reshape it to make it work?

Comment: Please post your code and the error message.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your response variable is. Is it `satisfaction`? If so, it seems like [*ordinal* logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit) would be more appropriate than multinomial. The UCLA stats website has a guide to [ordinal logistic regression in R](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm) that might be helpful to you as well.

Comment: Consider using the `multinom` function in the `nnet` package instead. `multinom(satisfaction ~ ..., data=dat)` will automatically reshape `satisfaction` into a multinomial array with *minimum* being treated as the referent level (as opposed to SAS using the first value in the data).

Comment: Try to first reshape your data into person-choice (long) format with `datL <- mlogit.data(dat, choice="satisfaction", shape="wide", varying=NULL)`. Then call `mlogit(satisfaction ~ 0 | education, reflevel="1", data=datL)`. More info can be found with `vignette("mlogit")` - especially on page 3ff.

Answer (score 0):

I would include an alt variable that would indicate the alternative 1 to 5. Your dependent variable is the "mode" variable that should be either `TRUE` or `FALSE` after you have reshaped your data into the `mlogit` format.